# How to get list of the grouped value of group by LINQ extension

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-core

I have a very simple LINQ statement which uses `Groupby` extension as follows

```
var v = _context.Rooms
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.postSubjectId, g.postSubject.subjectName })
    .Select(s => new { RoomName = s.Key.subjectName, MembersCount = s.Count() })
    .ToList();
```

And there is no problem with it.

But, *when I try to get the grouped list it turns back with an error.*

**the failed attempt**

```
var v = _context.Rooms
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.postSubjectId, g.postSubject.subjectName })
    .Select(s => new { RoomName = s.Key.subjectName, MembersCount = s.Count(), MemberIds = s.Select(v=>v.MemberId).ToList() })
    .ToList();
```

**The error**

> InvalidOperationException: The LINQ expression
> `'(GroupByShaperExpression: KeySelector: new { postSubjectId = (r.postSubjectId), subjectName = (p.subjectName) }, ElementSelector:(EntityShaperExpression: EntityType: Room ValueBufferExpression: (ProjectionBindingExpression: EmptyProjectionMember) IsNullable: False ) ) .Select(v => v.MemberId)'`
> could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can
> be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting
> a call to either `AsEnumerable()`, `AsAsyncEnumerable()`, `ToList()`, or
> `ToListAsync()`. See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.

And here are my Models and ViewModel

**Room**

```
public class Room
{
    public Guid Id { get; set; }

    public Guid? postSubjectId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("postSubjectId")]
    public PostSubject postSubject { get; set; }


    public string MemberId { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("MemberId")]
    public AppUser Member { get; set; } // extended Identity
}
```

**PostSubject**

```
public class PostSubject
{
    [Key]
    public Guid Id { get; set; }
    public string subjectName { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Room> rooms { get; set; }
}
```

[image]

Comment: Please [edit] your question to show what error you get when using grouped list.

Comment: @MOHAMEDABUELATTA The exception says that the `MemberIds = s.Select(v=>v.MemberId).ToList()` part can't be translated to database query, that's why the suggested fix is to materialize the query with `AsEnumerable` / `ToList` (or with their async counterpart) and perform the operation on client-side against in-memory collection.

Comment: So a quick and dirty fix might be following: `.Select(s => new { RoomName = s.Key.subjectName, MembersCount = s.Count(), Members = s})` and then perform a new `Select` against `v`, like `v.Select(s => new {s.RoomName, s.MemberCount, MemberIds = s.Members.Select(v=>v.MemberId).ToList())`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is SQL limitation. You cannot get records of the group. For such case you have to do client-side grouping, but before limit of returned data:

```cs
var v = _context.Rooms
    .Select(r => new { r.postSubjectId, r.postSubject.subjectName, r.MemberId })
    .AsEnumerable()
    .GroupBy(g => new { g.postSubjectId, g.subjectName })
    .Select(s => new { RoomName = s.Key.subjectName, MembersCount = s.Count(), MemberIds = s.Select(v => v.MemberId).ToList() })
    .ToList();
```